# Why does MobX allow me to change this property without @action?

Tags: javascript, mobx

Why does MobX in strict mode allow me to change the flag from the toggle method called from the constructor? Shouldn't it tell me "mobx is in strict mode, you should use an action"?

Code follows

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });


class Test {
    @observable flag = false;

    constructor() {
        this.toggle();
    }

    toggle() {
        this.flag = !this.flag;
    }
}

var t = new Test();

autorun(function test () {
    console.log("fired: " + t.flag);  //prints fired: true
});
```

Comment: What version of mobx are you pulling in?

Comment: I'm using mobx 4.1.1

Comment: Hmmm, I just added the configure to my code and immediately I see this in the console: `Since strict-mode is enabled, changing observed observable values outside actions is not allowed. Please wrap the code in an 'action' if this change is intended. Tried to modify: ObservableObject@1.playSpots[..].state`

Comment: However, my state changes are not in the class constructor. Maybe the strictness is not applied during constructor execution.

Comment: Based on reading through the code in observablevalue.ts, it looks to me like your observable properties are not observable until after the constructor has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @ChrisEdgington, properties are only turned into observable after the construct has been called, which is also logical since object wouldn't exist before constructor is called.

You are just basically initializing the `flag` field twice and i would dis-advice you from doing that.

```
class Test {
    @observable flag = true;
}
// is the same as:
class Test {
    @observable flag;
    constructor() {
        this.flag = true;
    }
}
```

So just use one but not both ways.